# VIo.com third party Implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, nullreferenceexception, restsharp

I am Implementing a third party API labeld with VIO.com and I am implementing in my ASP NET core web API and I am getting null refrence error when I send the request to the third party and In call stack I get the following error
1)
Cut.Infrastructure.dll!Cut.Infrastructure.Services.RestsharpService.Post<Cut.Application.ServiceModels.VioServiceModel.VioSearHotelReponseModel>(string endPoint, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> headers, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> parameters, string contentType) Line 47  C#
2)
Cut.Infrastructure.dll!Cut.Infrastructure.Services.VioService.SearchHotelReponse(Cut.Application.ServiceModels.VioServiceModel.VioInputHotelModel inpuHtotelModel) Line 33  C#
3)
Cut.Infrastructure.dll!Cut.Infrastructure.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegate next) Line 25  C#
Cut.Api.dll!Cut.Api.Controllers.HotelsController.VioSearchHotel(Cut.Application.ServiceModels.VioServiceModel.VioInputHotelModel vioInputHotelModel) Line 81    C#

4)
Cut.Application.dll!Cut.Application.PipelineBehaviors.ValidationBehaviour<Cut.Application.Features.Plans.Commands.VioHotelCommand, Cut.Common.Results.IDataResult<System.Collections.Generic.List<Cut.Application.ServiceModels.VioServiceModel.VioHotelResponse>>>.Handle(Cut.Application.Features.Plans.Commands.VioHotelCommand
5)
request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, MediatR.RequestHandlerDelegate<Cut.Common.Results.IDataResult<System.Collections.Generic.List<Cut.Application.ServiceModels.VioServiceModel.VioHotelResponse>>> next) Line 28    C#
6)
Cut.Application.dll!Cut.Application.Features.Plans.Commands.VioHotelCommand.VioHotelCommandHandler.Handle(Cut.Application.Features.Plans.Commands.VioHotelCommand command, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 23    C#

I had compared with my other API services and and I do not found any thing wrong with it can you I got this error first time can you people please help me to solve my problems I shall be veru thank full to you guyes
Thanks in advanced